# Is it necessary (in Python 2.7) to create an argument for global variables when writing a function?

Tags: python, function, variables, global, jython

Let's say I declare a variable in my global namespace and within the same namespace I create a function which references that variable.

```
name = "Franz"

def write_hi():
    print(name)

write_hi()
```

What are the benefits of creating an extra argument for the variable **name** like so:

```
name = "Franz"

def write_hi(name):
    print(name)

write_hi(name=name)
```

Would that even be possible given that the program now has a local and a global variable with the same name to deal with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables and function parameters don't really align in terms of what they do.

Global variables are super useful if they are required at the global scope, meaning multiple different methods require using it and it either is a constant which never gets changed or it is a state variable which needs to be accessed or updated frequently.

Function parameters allow the flow of the program to be changed. If you had a parameter for `write_hi`, it would allow what is printed to be changed from function call to function call. If you did not, it would run the same code each time, or at the very least you would have to modify the `name` variable.

There's nothing wrong or right about either of them. It's all about what you need at a particular moment.

In terms of whether or not its possible – it is! Your local variable is in a tighter scope than the global variable, so what'll happen is you will lose the ability to access your global `name` variable within that method.